FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase Blocking Thread #0
these days I'm facing an issue that does not allow me to run a React Native project on Android devices, it crashes as soon as it's launched. Instead, it works ok on iOS devices.
It's a complex project on which so many people have worked on, so it is difficult to have a complete track of all the developments made over the years.
This is the log of the error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase Blocking Thread #0
  Process: com.app.MyApp, PID: 15882
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkNotGoogleApiHandlerThread()V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions' appears in /data/app/~~1MEi9R6kd8rP9d1okoXlBg==/com.app.MyApp-Zns5nVqwixkl4DB8j_rd5A==/base.apk)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:2)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.openHttpURLConnection(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:487)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:163)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:533)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:387)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$3$FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:372)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.-$$Lambda$FirebaseInstallations$Kl2wdAe5utVajeTmV5LyfWUz3Bo.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:117)
    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:229)
    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.-$$Lambda$CustomThreadFactory$25wFMnJXuxCXflRCTG3ggSOiDOE.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

It's a problem that has appeared since the beginning of May 2024, before now it had not given any kind of failures.
I think it's related to the usage of firebase push notifications, maybe some libraries that are no longer compatible, but I'm not succeding in finding a working combination.
I also attach the build.gradle files
android/build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"

        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        supportLibVersion   = "30.0.0"
        //firebaseVersion = "17.3.4" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}


android/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for in debug.
 */
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1087
        versionName "2.10" 
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
     splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.

            //if release for play store
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2,]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
    version {
        strictly '1.3.1'
    }
}
    

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    
    compile (project(':react-native-push-notification')) { exclude group: 'com.facebook.react', module: 'react-native' }

    compile project(':RNMail')

    //implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0') { exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion}", "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1"
}

I tried to use and sync different versions of "googlePlayServicesVersion" ("11.8.0", "17.0.2", "18.1.0", ...) in android/build.gradle, use different versions of "buildToolsVersion" in android/build.gradle, use different versions of "firebaseMessagingVersion" in android/build.gradle, use different JDKs, update Android Studio "2023.3.1", ...
Expectation:
run the project on Android devices.
Please help :(

Update all the libraries of rn firebase to latest it will work. It worked for me

Try to remove
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1"

from configurations.all or change it version to 18.3.0
